# Is os.path.join a pure function

Tags: python, functional-programming

The function `os.path.join` in Python concatenates file and folder names to a long single path string according to the rules of the OS it is running on. For example on OS X it looks like

```
>>> import os 
>>> os.path.join('Project', 'Docs', 'data.csv')
'Project/Docs/data.csv'
```

On other os's the output might look different. So the output of the function depends on the OS. Now I wonder if we can still call this function pure? I want to use it in another function and I want that other function to be a pure function so I wonder if using `os.path.join` breaks purity.

Comment: What definition of "pure function" are you using?

Comment: @JohnGordon I do not know, will probably be part of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

`os.path` is actually an alias for an OS-specific module, so really there are multiple pure functions that `os.path.join`  might refer to.

For example,

```
$ import os.path
$ os.path.__name__
'posixpath'
```

On a POSIX operating system, `os.path.join` is really `posixpath.join`; on Windows it's `ntpath.join`, etc. You can see the various `*path.py` modules at https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib; each contains its own definition of `join`.

(`ntpath.join` may not be pure, depending on your notion of purity. It uses a global `ntpath.sep` which, in theory, could be modified between calls. It's "pure", though, if you consider that a read-only constant. But in general, `join` has no reason *not* to be pure.)